# sum with angular JS v1.5.5

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 First Number: <input type="text" ng-model="firstNum"><br>
Last Number: <input type="text" ng-model="lastNum"><br>
<br>
Result: {{firstNum + lastNum}}

</div>
```

I have problem adding, because concatenate both built-in numbers but not adding, Also, when the input is empty I get NULL.

Check other post, And I do not know why it does not come to me.

Here is an image.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAFhv.png)

I have my application in phalcon and change the estructure Angular:

```
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

To discard the angular version, remove it from my application and try with Angular [v1.5.5 and v1.6.2] and pure HTML and it works fine.

But in my application that works with phalcon, AngularJS I also use
the ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js, because the addition process I do in the modal,I guess some conflict is going on with ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js, Because there comes the problem, It does not sum up well and It doesn't add up well.

These are the scripts I use in my application : [script of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fvVU.png)

I do not know how to solve it, some help would be important.

Comment: Check my answer :)
But in case, on your screenshot, your first input field type seems to be `number` and not `text`. Maybe it causes this thing

Comment: Use `type="number"`

Comment: Checked with type = "number";
And just in the image that shows up is with type="number", I don't know if they noticed

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a Plunker, it works well !

I used Angular 1.5.5 & the last 1.6.2, didn't get this NULL

You may assign default values for you ng-model ?

Plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/Z14d8wCNjhY8ht7TwQhB?p=preview

Check it and tell me if `script.js` is different than yours, but I can tell you it's well working.

Comment: not working for me...concatenates as strings which is expected using `text` input

Comment: Your work is correct friend, probe with angular only and works well.
The problem is that the sum I do in a floating modal and I use in my application angular-route.min.js [AngularJS v1.6.2], 
I guess some conflict is going on, Because there comes the problem,
It does not sum up well and It doesn't add up well

Comment: Just change type = "number" no text, to work well #charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{firstNum.toString() + lastNum.toString()}}
```

toString() will solve the "null" text things, and also concat function with +

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

**Change from type="text" to type="number" (HTML5)**
**Try following code**

type="number"

**or you can keep html as it is**
**Try following code (change just expression)**

Result: {{(firstNum - 0) + (lastNum - 0)}}